# Angular 7 material table with dynamic headers and cells

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

considering that I get an array of objects from an API like this (the user has select boxes to chose the year, the type and input a value) :

```
[
  {
    "year": 2019,
    "type": "Salaries",
    "value": 100
  },
  {
    "year": 2019,
    "type": "Projects",
    "value": 78
  },
  {
    "year": 2018,
    "type": "Projects",
    "value": 500
  },
  {
    "year": 2018,
    "type": "Others",
    "value": 500
  },
]
```

I need to display this data per year like this :

```
| Year | Salaries | Pojects | Others |
-------------------------------------
| 2019 |   100    | 78      |        |
-------------------------------------
| 2018 |          | 500     | 500    |
```

The part that I couldn't figure out is how to loop through the array to build the array headers, then for each year put the right value on the corresponding type...thanks for your help.

Comment: Angular material documentation is supposed to explain that, with example. See: https://v6.material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Comment: @Flo I don't think you've read the question carefully (nor the documentation you're linking) because unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: You may have to transform your data to the right format. 
Every documentation's example tables have headers, every examples use JSON data, every examples show HTML, TS and CSS code. What more do you need ? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you need to create a new array by using data which received from the API. To give my solution, I will assume you received data array like below from the API.

```
[{ "year": 2019, "type": "Salaries", "value": 100 },
 { "year": 2019, "type": "Projects", "value": 78 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Projects", "value": 500 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Others", "value": 500 },
 { "year": 2019, "type": "Others", "value": 230 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Salaries", "value": 900 }]
```

To show above data in a table like in your question, you have to convert it to meaningful array like below.

```
[{ "year": 2019, "salary": 100, "project": 78, "other": 230 },
    { "year": 2018, "salary": 900, "project": 500, "other": 500 }]
```

**I assume there are no duplicate records for a certain year with same type like below.**

```
{ "year": 2019, "type": "Salaries", "value": 100 }
{ "year": 2019, "type": "Salaries", "value": 200 }
```

If there are duplicates like above **last element's value will be taken as the value**.

You have to implement new function to create the `displayData` array as follows.

**TypeScript**

```
export class MyComponent  {
  data = [
 { "year": 2019, "type": "Salaries", "value": 100 },
 { "year": 2019, "type": "Projects", "value": 78 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Projects", "value": 500 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Others", "value": 500 },
 { "year": 2019, "type": "Others", "value": 230 },
 { "year": 2018, "type": "Salaries", "value": 900 }];

displayData: any = [];

 constructor() {
   this.createDisplayData()
 }

 createDisplayData(): void {

   for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {

      let type: string;

      if (this.data[i].type === "Salaries")
        type = 'salary';
      else if (this.data[i].type === "Projects") 
        type = 'project';
      else 
        type = 'other';

     const found = this.displayData.find(v => v.year === this.data[i].year);

     if (!found) {
       let object = {};
       object['year'] = this.data[i].year;
       object[type] = this.data[i].value
       this.displayData.push(object);
     }
     else {
       found[type] = this.data[i].value;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Salaries</th>
    <th>Pojects</th>
    <th>Others</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of displayData">
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.year}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.salary}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.project}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.other}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Find [StackBlitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57115623?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).**

> **Update on suggestion by Comment.**

Other way you can do this is using **`Array.reduce()`** function instead of for loop is as follows.

**TS**

```
 createDisplayData(): void {

   this.displayData = this.data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {

     const found = accumulator.find(v => v.year === currentValue.year);
     if (!found) {

       let object = {};
       object['year'] = currentValue.year;
       object[currentValue.type] = currentValue.value;
       accumulator.push(object);
     } else {

       found[currentValue.type] = currentValue.value;
     }
     return accumulator;
   }, []);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Year</th>
    <th>Salaries</th>
    <th>Pojects</th>
    <th>Others</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let data of displayData">
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.year}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.Salaries}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.Projects}}</td>
    <td style="text-align: center">{{data.Others}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Find [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-57115623-reduce?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Comment: You can avoid that nasty loop if you use the `reduce()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to display data per year, you can use the year as your unique identifier. Just loop through the objects and create a new object like below:

```
let dataPerYear = {}

response
    .forEach(function (data) {
        if (!dataPerYear[data.year]) {
            dataPerYear[data.year] = {
                year: data.year
            }
        }

        dataPerYear[data.year][data.type] = [data.value]
    })
```

that should result in

```
{
    2019: {
        year: 2019,
        Salaries: 100,
        Projects: 78
    }
}
```

then, if you want it as an array:

```
let arrayData = Object.values(result)
```

will result in:

```
[
    {
        year: 2019,
        Salaries: 100,
        Projects: 78
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could map your collection into the shape you want for that table using `reduce()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Then simply map the fields to the Material table like you normally would.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "year": 2019,
    "type": "Salaries",
    "value": 100
  },
  {
    "year": 2019,
    "type": "Projects",
    "value": 78
  },
  {
    "year": 2018,
    "type": "Projects",
    "value": 500
  },
  {
    "year": 2018,
    "type": "Others",
    "value": 500
  },
]

const mappedData = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const match = acc.find(x => x.year === item.year);
  const transformed = {
    year: item.year,
    projects: item.type === "Projects" ? item.value : 0,
    salaries: item.type === "Salaries" ? item.value : 0,
    others: item.type === "Others" ? item.value : 0
  };
  
  if (match) {
    match.projects += transformed.projects;
    match.salaries += transformed.salaries;
    match.others += transformed.others;
  } else {
    acc.push(transformed);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(mappedData);
```